# Icon with TexturePaint throws InternalError: Surface not cachable

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d, java-2d

I have a custom `Icon` which uses a `TexturePaint` as paint and calls `fillPolygon` on a `Graphics2D` object.

This code works fine on JDK6 and JDK7, but fails under JDK8 with 64bit Linux (tried most recent JDK1.8 on 64bit Linux). On Windows, this runs fine with JDK8.

Output of the `java -version` command for the JDK used to reproduce the issue.

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Code to reproduce the issue:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TexturePaintIconTest {

  private static class CustomIcon implements Icon{

    private static final int[] sXArray = new int[]{2, 5, 7, 12, 12, 4, 1, 1, 2};
    private static final int[] sYArray = new int[]{4, 4, 2, 2, 11, 11, 8, 5, 4};
    private static final int sNumberOfPoints = 9;

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
      g.translate(x,y);

      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      Color fillColor = new Color( 140, 25, 25, 35);
      g2d.setPaint(createPatternPaint(fillColor));
      g2d.fillPolygon(sXArray, sYArray, sNumberOfPoints);

      g.translate(-x, -y);
    }

    private Paint createPatternPaint(Color color ){
      int[] colors = new int[]{color.getRGB(), 0};
      IndexColorModel colorModel = new IndexColorModel(1, 2, colors, 0, true, -1, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
      BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(2, 2, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED, colorModel);
      DataBufferByte dataBuffer = (DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
      byte[] data = dataBuffer.getData();
      data[0] = 0;
      data[1] = 1;
      data[2] = 1;
      data[3] = 0;
      return new TexturePaint(image, new Rectangle(2, 2));
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
      return 16;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
      return 16;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame testFrame = new JFrame("TestFrame");

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label with icon", new CustomIcon(), SwingConstants.LEFT);
        testFrame.add(label);

        testFrame.pack();
        testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        testFrame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Running the `main` method results in the following error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.InternalError: Surface not cachable
    at sun.java2d.xr.XRPaints$XRTexture.getAccSrcSurface(XRPaints.java:211)
    at sun.java2d.xr.XRPaints$XRTexture.isPaintValid(XRPaints.java:224)
    at sun.java2d.xr.XRPaints.isValid(XRPaints.java:75)
    at sun.java2d.xr.XRSurfaceData.getMaskFill(XRSurfaceData.java:205)
    at sun.java2d.SurfaceData.validatePipe(SurfaceData.java:675)
    at sun.java2d.xr.XRSurfaceData.validatePipe(XRSurfaceData.java:123)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.validatePipe(SunGraphics2D.java:446)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.validate(ValidatePipe.java:55)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.fillPolygon(ValidatePipe.java:147)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.fillPolygon(SunGraphics2D.java:2389)
    at com.luciad.internal.lucy.map.TexturePaintIconTest$CustomIcon.paintIcon(TexturePaintIconTest.java:22)
```

I already searched in the Java bug database ([official one](http://bugs.java.com/) and the [openjdk one](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net)) but found no bug report which could explain this. Am I doing something wrong with my custom icon, or did I stumble upon a JDK bug ?

Comment: In your place I would open a new bug report

Comment: @lbalazscs I did that yesterday and it is currently under review. Just asked it here first to see whether I didn't simply did something stupid in my code which I overlooked

Answer (score 0):

If the same code works differently depending on the JVM must be a bug, since it's the only OS-specific part of your code